# How to upgrade a python libraries which were installed on python 3.7 VENV to python 3.9 VENV?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I had a Flask app project deployed on Debian-9 VM, which upgraded to Debian-11, and my app stopped working because of global-Python, which is 3.7 in Debian-9 and 3.9 in Debian-11.

You can see the problem in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75861000/problem-with-building-scikit-learn-for-flask-api-on-debian-vm).

However, my question here is what is the best way to upgrade libraries from Python 3.7 to 3.9 or, to say it in a simple way, how to update libraries to the latest versions?

My concern here is when the libraries are too old, and you upgrade them, most of the time, the syntaxes are changed, and the app stop working. In a normal Python app, you can see the code line which is the source of the problem and one by one you can debug the problem and integrate the code into the new version of libraries but I do not know how to do it in flask app because when I have version problem the flask server simply does not start!

Comment: From your project directory, `pip install pip-upgrader` and  `pip-upgrade`.

Comment: Yeah I explained that when I do that the app stop working because of version control and dependencies

Comment: Which venv management tool are you using?  Try google "upgrade python version in venv with <that-tool>".

Comment: I think I use the most common one, which is virtual environments(venv). What do you mean by "try google" ?

Comment: Try searching on google.com (or your favorite search engine). Typically what you do is configure your venv to use the new python version, then reinstall the dependencies. The exact steps depend on which tool you use.

Comment: That is the problem the project is not small and has around 50 libraries, most of which depend on each other. I should add that I have experience, and I am not a newbie that you tell to use Google :)  
if you had time and put some time into reading the whole thing, that would help me!